# Admin local navigation tabs in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

While populating admin menu using `INavigationProvider` we can add items and use `LocalNav()` method. This way we have navigation tabs in content area.

In my case I have my custom module, which lists content items of specific `ContentType`. Then I can click selected content item and navigate inside to *child* documents. 
Here I need to show 3 tabs with lists of child documents.

The question is: how to dynamically create this tabs?

Orchard renders this tabs using `Layout.LocalNavigation` zone, which has `List` of `MenuItem`'s marked with `LocalNav = true`.

How do I add my own tabs to this list? 
(tab `href` depends on parent item `ID`, like `/admin/MyModule/Index/123/questions` where `123` is `ID` of parent document)

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't give specific advice on getting at the product data from the route, but as far as dynamic tabs, I had a similar situation come up recently, here's how I did it; basically, I needed a separate tab for every installed culture on the site.

```
public void GetNavigation(NavigationBuilder builder)
{
var cultures = this.CultureManager.ListCultures().ToList();
builder
.Add(
T("Settings"), 
menu => menu.Add(
    T("Culture Customizations"), 
    "10.0", 
    subMenu =>
    {
        subMenu.LinkToFirstChild(true);
        for (int cultureCounter = 0; cultureCounter < cultures.Count; cultureCounter++)
        {
            var cultureString = cultures[cultureCounter];
            var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cultureString);
            subMenu.Add(T(cultureInfo.EnglishName), cultureCounter.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), item => item.Action("Index", "Admin", new {area = "ProjectName.YourModule", cultureCode = cultureString}).LocalNav(true));
        }
    }));
```

}